# Maintain access to the implicit receiver `self` when evaluating a block in Class.new?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Sometimes when APIs call for the use of blocks, I find it frustrating when I realise they are rebinding `self`, therefore taking me out of the current implicit receiver context.  Usually I just do something like assign a local variable `me = self` before the block, then invoke methods on that.  It feels like a hack.  Is there a "correct" way to do this?  Sort of like implicitly inserting the current `self` into the inheritance hierarchy of the new class?

```
class ClassMaker
  def do_something_complex
  end

  def make_a_class
    me = self
    Class.new do
      me.do_something_complex # <-- This
    end
  end
end
```

When the blocks are repeated across a series of methods in the same class, you have to copy `self` repeatedly, which seems messy and like there's probably a better way?  This doesn't only apply to `Class.new`, but to anything that changes the implicit receiver.

UPDATE: This is interesting, though it doesn't solve the problem unless you can rewrite the API you're forced to work with: http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/ruby-dsls-instance-eval-with-delegation (note that the "API" I'm currently working with is Sinatra:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  def self.some_method
  end

  get "/" do
    yadda_yadda(some_method) # <-- can't do this!
  end
end
```

Maybe I'm missing the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please note that you can't rebind `self` in Ruby, so that's not what happening. Instead the  there are certain points in Ruby where `self` changes, it's a good idea to [read up on that](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2007/11/changing-self-i.html).
2. In the Sinatra example it's kinda obvious that you can't do this, since `some_method` is a class method and they need an explicit receiver. Try something like `self.class.some_method` and it should work.
3. Your "hack" isn't so uncommon, you'll often see `klass` as the variable name instead of `me`.

Looking at your code I wonder if your problem lies in trying to port over a pattern from some other language and not knowing how to go about it in Ruby. Maybe with more context we'd be able to better help.

Comment: Great answer.  With regards to the Sinatra thing, however, `self` does change, so `self.class` actually points to some anonymous class :)  Nope, not trying to bring across a concept from another language, I'm building a Sinatra app almost purely through metaprogramming (synthesizing a RESTful API that loosely wraps a set of DataMapper models).  I had to actually split common methods out into a module, then mix that module into the `helpers` in Sinatra.

Comment: Re Sinatra: the class method thing with the explicit receiver is still true, but I must admit I didn't look at the definition of `get` to see what it does behind the scenes, but from what you say it seems to define a singleton or something. Hope I could at least help a little.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure there's basically no way around this, so your answer is accepted, thanks :)